# How to resolve "JOIN expression not supported"?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This query is causing a "JOIN expression not supported" error:

```
select * from (reclassdata r
left join
crsubstatus cs
on
r.namebillinglog=cs.recordedstatusperson)
left join
role_task rt
on
r.role=rt.role
and
cs.recordedstatus=rt.task
```

The problem appears to be trying to join the one table `role_task` to two other tables `reclassdata` and `crsubstatus`, as the query runs successfully if I rewrite it as:

```
select * from (select * from reclassdata r
left join
crsubstatus cs
on
r.namebillinglog=cs.recordedstatusperson) x
left join
role_task rt
on
x.role=rt.role
and
x.recordedstatus=rt.task
```

But then I'm using an extra `select *` and I'd rather not have that performance hit.  Is there a way to resolve the "JOIN expression not supported" error without the extra `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets.

```
select * 
from reclassdata r
left join crsubstatus cs on r.namebillinglog = cs.recordedstatusperson
left join role_task rt on r.role = rt.role and cs.recordedstatus=rt.task
```

Comment: See my comment on Bob Jarvis' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a subquery is the only way to go.  The query you posted is considered an ambiguous outer join because Jet doesn't know which left join to evaluate first:

```
select * from reclassdata r left join
(SELECT * from
crsubstatus cs left join
role_task rt on cs.recordedstatus=rt.task) t
on r.role=t.role and r.namebillinglog=t.recordedstatusperson
```

If you're worried about a performance hit you might move the subquery to a separate query.  It may help.  If performance is still poor you may have to resort to throwing the subquery results into an indexed table, then linking back to it in the query.